# Matching records between 2 lists of files (using awk?)

Tags: bash, awk

I have 2 sets of files as follows:

> add_*
>
> upd_*

(What's represented by the * is just making for a unique file name in the context)

> add_* files contain:   with space seperators
>
> upd_* files contain:

Now, I want to get a list of all values for  actually has a match in  (or vice versa, since it's the same result). I feel I should be able to do this in awk, but I've been struggling because of the multiple file input thing.

Here's a concrete example using simplified data:

add_1001

> ABC123 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> DEF234 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

add_1002

> EFG987 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

add_1003

> ABC123 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

add_1004

> XYZ666 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

upd_9001

> ABC123

upd_9002

> XYZ666
>
> LMN001

upd_9003

> UUU_123

So here I would want the following list produced

> ABC123
>
> XYZ666

If I get a double for ABC123, it's no problem. Likewise if the output is actually the rows from the add_* files that include the rest of the data.

I realise I can concatenate all the files first if need be, but I can't help feeling I can solve this without doing that, and we're talking potentially a lot of files and an extremely performance sensitive routine, so just reading them once is preferable.

I hope I've explained myself well enough!

Comment: This is not particularly clear. Do you want to output all "keys" from all `add` files that are also present in one of the `upd` files?

Comment: How large, and how sensitive? I am thinking you could just concatenate the files on the fly, pipe them into sort and use comm to highlight the matches.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Basically, yes.

Comment: @HellmarBecker It's a cacheing system for data that's commonly accessed by front end systems, so how much entirely depends on what's happening at any given time in the system. If large updates (eg. end of month billing) have just been run, then it can be an awful lot of data. "Regular" loads will probably be handling much smaller amounts, but it needs to scale.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
grep -F -f <(cat upd_*) add_*
```

Or if tokens are separated with spaces

```
grep -F -f <(cat upd_*| tr ' ' '\n') add_*
```

Or to display only match without filenames

```
grep -F -f <(cat upd_*| tr ' ' '\n') -h -o add_*
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is probably the simplest way of doing it! I was just overcomplicating matters trying to force it into awk :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be `comm -12 <(sort add_*) <(sort upd_*)`

Check if it performs well enough, most likely it will.

Comment: That works nicely with a minor amendment to only take the first field from the add files: 

`comm -12 <(sort add_* | cut -d" " -f1) <(sort upd_*)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an `awk` solution:

```
awk 'FILENAME ~ "upd" {data[$1]=1; next}
    {if ($1 in data) { print $0; delete data[$1]}}' upd_* add_*
```